# Approaches to store and serve images in a large image-based project

Tags: php, save, gallery

I have a big project on the hand.

It is based on images and galleries.

In this website there are three different sizes of an an image.
Original Size, Thumbnail Size, Tiny Size

I have a dedicated server for this project, so spacing is not my main concern, though I should watch it and just to a logical concern there is no limit.

**My Question**: Which method is better to save images when posted onto the site?

- Saving all three sizes in three different files the moment they are posted
- Or resizing them on the fly when loaded into the page, which means just to keep original image

**Priorities**:

1. Quality
2. Performance
3. Storage

Comment: The better way is resizing them on the fly when loaded onto the page. Doing this will prevent the quality and less uses of Storage.

Also for on the fly resizing, you should use some libraries which make cache of the image, it will increase performance also.

Comment: Do you store it on the server itselves then you would have to look out for manipulations aswell... I used a database with type blop

Comment: I store it on the server, blob is a strongly recommended NOT to be used

Comment: @Mostafa Can you please substantiate your comment to avoid storing images in a blob?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't generate on the fly (especially with long image lists that a visitor looks at, performance COULD drop, depending on the way you handle it). Also depends how big the original size is. I'd go for the 'generate once' strategy anyway and cache it client side. This way you can also crank up the quality of the image on resizing and don't worry too much on server impact (could get a real issue, depending on specs and simultaneous visitors, uplink etc.).

Just my 2c.

Comment: I personally prefer to write a class for convenient resizing once they are going to be saved onto the server...yes, I don't like on-the-fly resizing since it will consume memory each time a request arrives

Comment: @Mustafa, yes that would indeed be a good idea. Resize the uploaded (or otherwise received image) and resize it every time from the original (which is what I'd do). This way you'll preserve the best image quality. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're listing *Quality* as your top priority and *Storage* as the lowest. In that case, I'd store the images with the highest possible/acceptable resolution and resize them on the fly, possibly with a caching mechanism. **By and large, note that caching will also be performed by the browsers themselves**.

**EDIT**: that seems to be the way SO's avatar pictures (not the gravatar) are served (the image dimensions are passed in the request to get the image, try changing them).

Also, at this stage in your project it shouldn't be hard to implement both approaches and benchmark them against the expected load. However, I'd still start with images generated on the fly and precompute different resolutions at a later stage if caching doesn't help.

Comment: thanks. but a question soon arise regarding your approach. Isn't that an enemy against performance to do resizing each time a new image is visited, while we can do process that resizing once and allocate it a storage-block to...

Comment: @Mostafa Performance is an issue to be taken in a certain load context. As said, the classical way is to back this approach by a caching mechanism which will also help beyond the mere question of image resizing but also w.r.t. disk reads. A definite answer to the question will depend on the application at hand. All I am pointing out is, for reasonable original dimensions, resizing on the fly [+caching] is a solution chosen by many. **Keep in mind that caching will also be done by the browser, thus hardly requiring more than one resizing at all per client**.

Comment: @Mostafa Also, with image preprocessing, one is constraining the system with constants such as dimensions, quality and resizing algorithm. I would forgo a somewhat _plastic_ approach for a more responsive one if I can afford to do so.